# Action is being dispatched but functionality is not working in Redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am dispatching saveShippingAddress from ShippingScreen.js and in redux devtools it shows saveShippingAddress being dispatched but the it's functionality in shippingAddressSlice.js is not working. I have tried to add other actions in reducers but they are also not working

**ShippingScreen.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import FormContainer from '../components/FormContainer';
import { saveShippingAddress } from '../features/shippingAddressSlice';
const ShippingScreen = () => {
  const cart = useSelector((store) => store.cart);
  const { shippingAddress } = cart;
  console.log(shippingAddress);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [address, setAddress] = useState(shippingAddress.address);
  const [city, setCity] = useState(shippingAddress.city);
  const [postalCode, setPostalCode] = useState(shippingAddress.country);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(shippingAddress.country);
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(saveShippingAddress({ address, city, postalCode, country }));
    navigate('/payment');
  };
  return (
    <FormContainer>
      <h1>Shipping</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group controlId='address'>
          <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type='address'
            placeholder='Enter Address'
            value={address ? address : ''}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId='city'>
          <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type='city'
            placeholder='Enter City'
            value={city ? city : ''}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId='postalCode'>
          <Form.Label>postalcode</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type='text'
            placeholder='Enter postalcode'
            value={postalCode ? postalCode : ''}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setPostalCode(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId='country'>
          <Form.Label>Country</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type='text'
            placeholder='Enter Country name'
            value={country ? country : ''}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
        <Button variant='primary' type='submit'>
          Continue
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </FormContainer>
  );
};
export default ShippingScreen;
```

**shippingAddressSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
const initialState = {
  cartItems: [],
  shippingAddress: {},
};
const shippingAddressSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'ShippingAddress',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    saveShippingAddress: (state, action) => {
      console.log('hello');
      console.log(action.payload);
      // localStorage.setItem('shippingAdrress', JSON.stringify(action.payload));
      return {
        ...state,
        shippingAddress: action.payload,
      };
    },
  },
});
console.log(shippingAddressSlice);
export const { saveShippingAddress, closeModal } = shippingAddressSlice.actions;
export default shippingAddressSlice.reducer;
```

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import productListReducer from './features/productListFeature/productListSlice';
import productDetailsReducer from './features/productListFeature/productDetailSlice';
import CartReducer from './features/addToCart/cartSlice';
import userLoginReducer from './features/UserFeature/loginUserSlice';
import userRegisterReducer from './features/UserFeature/registerUserSlice';
import userDetailsReducer from './features/UserFeature/userDetailsSlice';
import userUpdateProfileReducer from './features/UserFeature/updateProfileSlice';
import ShippingAddressReducer from './features/shippingAddressSlice';


const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
  : [];

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
  : null; 
const shippingAddressFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shippingAddress'))
  : {};
const initialState = {
  cart: {
    cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage,
    shippingAddress: shippingAddressFromStorage,
  },
  userLogin: {
    userInfo: userInfoFromStorage,
  },
};

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    productList: productListReducer,
    productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
    cart: CartReducer,
    userLogin: userLoginReducer,
    userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
    userDetails: userDetailsReducer,
    userUpdateProfile: userUpdateProfileReducer,
shippingAddress: ShippingAddressReducer,
  },
  preloadedState: initialState, //for local storage
});
export default store;
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't wrap the app in a Provider?

Answer (score 0):

Internaly createSlice reducers uses an immer.
Could you try to change your reducer to:

```js
saveShippingAddress: (state, action) => {
      console.log('hello');
      console.log(action.payload);
      // localStorage.setItem('shippingAdrress', JSON.stringify(action.payload));
      state.shippingAddress = action.payload;
}
```

For more info I can suggest to visit https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#immer-usage-patterns

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. I saw in redux devtools that shipping address is set to the values entered in the form after clicking submit. You should clarify more on what is it that is not working. If it's giving any kind of error, kindly share.

Comment: No errors... I have added store.js please check it if there is any problem in it

Comment: Please add the reducer functions as well. Store.js seems to be fine. Or do one thing. Add the whole code in a react codesandbox and send the link.

Comment: I have found out the problem... I did not add reducer function in store.js

Comment: Now there is another problem that I am not getting data from local storage ... please check store.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73935230/unable-to-get-item-from-local-storage